# Why setSupportActionBar(toolbar) in line 31 is showing error? How could I resolve this?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

[image: Why is this showing error?]

I tried all the functionalities like creating another private function, and placing `findViewById(toolbar)` and already tried with placing `R.id.toolbar` at the place of toolbar inside the `setSupportActionBar`.

Comment: What is the error, when you hover your mouse

Comment: It shows, make a private function for setSupportActionBar

Answer (score 0):

In your case the isssue is:

> **Type mismatch**.
> Required: `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar?`
> Found: `android.widget.Toolbar`

Check your import. You have to use `androidx.appcompat.widget`.

```
//import android.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i tried it many times. It is not working. Errors are still coming.

Comment: @VaibhavPaliwal errors? In your screen there only 1 error

Comment: Yes sir, there is only one error, but it is not getting solved.